# how to change the color of that particular listTile for few time before going to next screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

if we are using
ListTile and all ListTile are in white color and by clicking on any listTile we go to the next screen.
how to change the color of that particular listTile for few time before going to next screen???

Answer (score 1):

Here you can call setState() in the widget containing the ListTile to change the state of the listtile with a variable e.g "**selected**" and then await for some seconds before pushing the new screen

```
ListView(
        children: List.generate(
          3,
          (index) {
            bool selected = false;
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState1) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "tile: $index",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  selected: selected,
                  selectedTileColor: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: () async {
                    setState1(() {
                      selected = true;
                    });

                    await Future.delayed(
                      Duration(
                        milliseconds: 600,
                      ),
                    );

                    await Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          body: Center(
                            child: Text("selected tile: $index"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );

                    setState1(() {
                      selected = false;
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      )
```

Comment: thanks man..   but if we don't use this               "await Future.delayed(
                      Duration(
                        milliseconds: 600,
                      ),
                    );  "                                                                                                                                                                                                        then also it works fine as "select = false" will not going to work until we come back to the screen so there is no use of Future.dalayed anyway  thanks